# Preg_match these two strings at once please. I am going regex mad

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How I hate regex! :'( Here's my code:

```
preg_match("/^stats_equals_([(.*)])_([(.*)])/", $tag, $fieldAndValue)?$tag:!$tag):
echo ">". $fieldAndValue[1];
echo ">". $fieldAndValue[2];
```

To which I am feeding the following string. You can see it might contain anything alphanumerical, or (semi) special characters, frequently underscores. Just never square brackets (Lest madness ensues!):

```
stats_equals_[foo1_foo]_[Bar2_bar]
```

I am expecting to see "foo1_foo" and "Bar2_bar" echoed.

The closest I have come is two repetitions of "foo1_foo" and it is clear to me now that I am just throwing expressions at it to see if anything sticks, when I should be talking to one of you regex experts!

The code above is where I quit, and it's echoing nothing at all.

Thanks very much.

Comment: For anyone that wants to test his regex: https://regex101.com/r/hNRLvw/1

Comment: @mkaatman Thanks for that, I should have thought of that myself :)

Comment: Your input contains a { but you're only matching if it starts with stats_squals (which also contains a typo it would seem.)

Comment: Typo and brackets corrected, it's not in my real code, I was just cutting characters for the question :) If anyone can match both strings in the regex tested @mkaatman set up I am golden, thanks

Comment: @mayersdesign I'm not sure if you want [this](https://regex101.com/r/hNRLvw/3)

Comment: Ok, just seen the answer ;-)

Comment: @horcrux Is that exactly the same as mine? haha. No problem, I appreciate your work on it. Please post the answer and I'll accept :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, by more or less guesswork and playing with the regex sandbox I hit this:

```
preg_match("/^stats_equals_\[(.*?)\]_\[(.*?)\]/", $tag, $fieldAndValue)?$tag:!$tag):]
```

Mostly my problem was caused by `[` and `]` being meta-characters which needed escaping.

You live and learn.